# How to Get HTML Given Name and Value Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to grab the html of an input element within a set of input elements. All of them have the same name, but different html and values. How can I grab the html from an input with a value of `theme` and a value equal to some number between 1-9?

Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="1" checked> Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="2"> Option 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="3"> Option 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="4"> Option 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="5"> Option 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="6"> Option 6<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="7"> Option 7<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="8"> Option 8<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="9"> Option 9<br>
```

Random scenario, I need to grab the html of the `input` with the `name=theme` and `value=4`, i.e. "Option 4".

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `label` or `span` to wrap you text beside your `radio button`. that way, it would be easier to target the text with `JQuery`

HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="1" checked><span> Option 1</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="2"><span> Option 2</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="3"><span> Option 3</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="4"><span> Option 4</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="5"><span> Option 5</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="6"><span> Option 6</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="7"><span> Option 7</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="8"><span> Option 8</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="9"><span> Option 9</span><br>
```

JS :

```
var tmp = $('input[name="theme"][value="4"]').next().text();
alert(tmp);
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/L8xzhu9u/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jquery attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('input[name="theme"][value="4"]').html();
```

Comment: Trying to pass value in from string, I have changed it to look like this: `$('input[name="theme"][value="'+array[2]+'"]')` but it is not working

Comment: What is `array` or specially `array[2]`?

Comment: @Ethan: Accept the answer. For more wizard tweaks involving unmentionned before arrays and loops... Ask another question.

Answer (score -2):

The input element doesn't have any text associated with it. Instead, you want to grab the next sibling and display the text content that it holds.

```
$('input[name="theme"][value="4"]').get(0).nextSibling.textContent;
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the 'Option 4' text in a span as previously mentioned.